# How to do digital sign pdf document using X.509 certificate in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, digital-signature, digital-certificate

Basically when i am run my application on my localhost i can get all installed certificate list in certificate store. But now same thing i am looking. Host application on server and get certificate list from end user machine and bind into dropdown list. Where user will select certificate and select pdf file then sign the document. That sign document will store on server/dowload files on user machine

Please help me.
Thanks.
Sorry for my bed English

```
public static List<X509Certificate2> GetCurrentUserCertificates()
        {
            List<X509Certificate2> certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>();
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                certificates.Add(cert);
            }
            return certificates;
        }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you have problem retrieving certificates on server? Then show your code how do you do that. Do you have problem ro display drop down list? Then show your code. Or do you have problem signing? Again show your code.

Comment: Yes @mentallurg, I not able to load certificates(.pfx) files list from end user system. Example. I had developed web application. I am running/Executing on my computer using visual studio 2010. In my computer i ad installed certificates files(Lets say A.pfx, B.pfx). When i am running my code on localhost. that is my computer. it will read certificates(A.pfx, B.pfx) list and bind into dropdown list. but same code i has deployed on server. No certificates found.